# private docker registry tls authentication with AWS ACM

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a private docker registry, which uses the domain.crt and domain.key for tls authentication, but few days before keys expired. Now i want to us AWS ACM certificate for the TLS. Problem is that AWS do not provide certificate's private key so is there any way i can use AWS ACM certificate for tls
Basically i want to somthing like this

        `- name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
          value: aws:arn:xxxxxxxxx
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
          value: aws:arn:xxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: I also want to know this